# Can't use QBFC5 in Windows 7 64 bit

Tags: sdk, quickbooks

We are trying to move an old client application from one PC to a new windows 7 64 bit PC. At the time the software was developed we used QBFC version 5 to interact with quickbooks, however it appears now that we can no longer do so. I attempted to register the interop.qbfc5lib.dll after installing the QBFC5 installation package and we still receive an error message. I've also attempted installing the most recent version of the SDK to the system and upgraded the QBRPXML2 to the most recent version. The client is now running QB2013 on the server and has updated his data to this version.

The error we are receiving is: "Retrieving the COM class factory for component with cLSID {4877276c-486d-b201-f096035ca4df} failed due to the following error: 80040154.

Suggestions other than recompile the code?

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem with a client who I had used QBFC 8 and he had switched to a new computer. I didn't do a lot of research, but it appears that the installers that Intuit has on their websites use different CLSID than I originally had built against. I just downloaded and installed QBFC 5, which I didn't have anything installed for, and it shows the following CLSID in the registry (I'm on Windows 7 64-bit):

QbFC5.QBOESessionManager {86AC2FAD-C987-4757-B591-02F9867A8BE5}
QbFC5.QBSessionManager {4877276C-A727-486D-B201-F096035CA4DF}

The only thing I can think of is that the COM files that were originally installed on your development machine have been changed in a later installation. For my client on QBFC8, I simply switched to using QBFC12 and recompiled the code.